# ORM: List of related items

Tags: php, lithium

I tried to use ORM to find list of provinces and their cities.

the result is same as this list:

```
"provinces": [
    {
        "name": "Prov.1",
        "Cities": {
            "name": "City.1"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Prov.1",
        "Cities": {
            "name": "City.2"
        }
    },
]
```

what is expected:

```
"provinces": [
    {
        "name": "Prov.1",
        "Cities": [
            {
                "name": "City.1"
            },
            {
                "name": "City.2"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

used ORM:

```
Provinces::find('all', [
    'with' => ['Cities']
]);
```

Comment: You will need to use any loop of your preference to iterate through this results to form the array you expect. The ORM will most certainly not deliver the results like that for you.

Comment: @Rafael - except not a `do{ }while();` loop any one but that.  Why is it JSON?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix it is converted. $model->to('json')

Comment: I generally consider `do{ } while();` a war crime, @ArtisticPhoenix :)

Comment: It has some nice niche uses, you can use it to `break` out of a control block, if you do `do{ }while(false)` it loops one time and lets you use `break` other then that I haven't found a use for it.

Comment: @RaminFirooz you'll want to re-structure it first.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
$array = [];
foreach($provinces as $province){
    $key = $province['name'];
    if(!isset($array[$key])){
       $array[$key] = [
         'name' => $province['name'], 
         'Cities' => [
              [ 'name' => $province['Cities']['name']];
          ]
       ];
    }else{
       $array[$key]['Cities'][] = ['name' => $province['Cities']['name']];
    }
}

 //strip keys
$array = array_values($array);
```

Because you don't have an actual PHP array posted I'm just guessing at what it should be.